# Which activity has launch this activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application their is an activity C which can be launched by two activities. How can i find which activity has launch the activity C ?? So that my activity can take action accordingly. Can anyone help .?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

**A.java**

```
    Intent send = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
    send.putExtra("name", "A Activity");
    startActivity(send);
```

**B.java**

```
    Intent send = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
    send.putExtra("name", "B Activity");
    startActivity(send);
```

**C.java**

```
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("name")){
         String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
         if(result.equals("A Activity")){
                //Do Someting
         }else if(result.equals("B Activity")){
                //Do Someting
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an string from intent when you launch an activity. From this string you can perform action what you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "activityName");
startActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a toast message or log message on activityA and activityB. So from this way you can know which activity has launch activityC.

eg.

Use below code in activityA button's click event.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Launched from A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and Use below code in activityA button's click event.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                   "Launched from B", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Edit**

based on your comment `i want my activity to know so that i can take actions accordingly` this,

you can have a static variable like

```
public static int a = 0;
```

then increment it in each activity and check the value, set in activityA as a 1 and activityB in 2 and then check condition,

```
if (a == 1){
// came from activityA
}else{
//came from activityB
}
```

Comment: No i want my activity to know so that i can take actions accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple... Use Logcat or Toast or Sysout

Log

```
Log.w("myApp", "C activity Called")
```

Toast

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "C Activity is Called!!! =)",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Sysout

```
System.out.println("C Activity called");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the intent you use to launch your activity C put an extra data which will store from where this activity,C, is launched. In the activity C when its launched get the extra and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just follow given below

**A to C**

```
Intent send = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
send.putExtra("FROM", "FROM_A");
startActivity(send);
```

**B to C**

```
Intent send = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
send.putExtra("FROM", "FROM_B");
startActivity(send);
```

**finally at C.java**

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("FROM")){
     String result = getIntent.getStringExtra("FROM");
}
```

You can also use activity manager to know, try with something like given below

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 &&
   taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
    Log.i(TAG, "This is last activity in the stack");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the simple `String` value in the intent and check for that value in the Activity C for which activity has launched the Activity C . Check out my code as below:

In your **Activity A**

```
 Intent intentA = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityC.class);
 intentA.putExtra("ActivityName", "ActivityA");
 startActivity(intentA);
```

In your **Activity B**

```
 Intent intentB = new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
 intentB.putExtra("ActivityName", "ActivityB");
 startActivity(intentB);
```

In your Activity C check for the value as below:

```
String activityName=getIntent().getStringExtra("ActivityName");
if(activityName.equalsIgnoreCase("ActivityA"))
   {
      //your logic
  }
else if(activityName.equalsIgnoreCase("ActivityB"))
  {
     // your logic 
  }
```